# Can not find the EventTrigger.SourceName

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard, eventtrigger

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Name="b1" Content="Button"/>
    <Rectangle Name="Mr1" Fill="Black">
        <Rectangle.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger SourceName="b1" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                 <code.../>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Rectangle.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

---

Error: can not find the b1.

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope of where the trigger collection (the collection that this Trigger is part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is **within the template that contains this Trigger**.

Answer (score 5):

I was just facing this same problem.. posting the solution for anyone else interested.

```
<Canvas>

    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MyAwesomeAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="Mr1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height">
            <!-- Some Awesome animation here..-->
        </Storyboard>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <Button Name="b1" Content="Button">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <!--The key is to define the click trigger on the button. Why should the rectangle know about the button?-->
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAwesomeAnimation}"></BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>

    <Rectangle Name="Mr1" Fill="Black" />

</Canvas>
```